# setTimeout nodejs performance

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am creating an angular app with node js express as backend. The angular app receives database rows as json and populates it. The ajax part is incredibly fast and users exploit the server by frequently performing requests. I want to add a delay to ajax in nodejs. I use setTimeout() to purposefully wait in nodejs middleware before the rendering route is executed. But i want to know if this is performance friendly or derogatory and should it be avoided?

Comment: I believe, client side request-rate restriction will be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js application should response as quickly as it can, or your requests will eat your memory.
You should add delay/restriction to client code, I believe.

Also, you should to setup your server to disallow flood requests (DDoS trying). Take a look to a [toobusy](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/01/building-a-node-js-server-that-wont-melt-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-5/) package.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're basically adding more work for the event loop, if you wish to create a fake delay, do it on the client side.